# FInding the latest message in a list of messages

Tags: python, selenium

so im currently trying to copy a message to automate a login sequence. The login requires an otp code that has to be sent to a phone. I set up a textnow account to gain access to the otp via web page but the problem comes in when trying to find the latest message. How could I specify that I want the latest element copied even though the html for each individual message looks exactly the same. The only thing that differentiates them is the otp given and time.

How could I identify the latest message to the bot and copy it ?[image]

```
senderofotp = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="chat-preview-list"] /ul/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span/div')
senderofotp.click()
```

The code above is how I selected the sender of the message.

```
message = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="messageView"]/ul/li[30]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/span/span')
```

even when I try to grab the message it gives me the xpath to the message view as a whole

Comment: Maybe scrape all of them, put them in a list, and get the last index

Comment: @Noah That's a good solution but how would go about listing all of that html ?

Comment: Using a for loop

Comment: You never mentioned which library in Python you are using? what is your existing code to get one of them?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail. I'm using selenium .

Comment: I would simply use `(//li[@class='chat-item incoming'])[last()]` xpath to get the latest item.

Answer (score 0):

you may use `find_elements_by_xpath` to find list of elements at once